# iOS Share Extension - How to access core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, ios-app-extension

I have a host application which fetches information from Core Data. Now i need a share extension which going to show some information from host app's data.

I have already enabled app group and defined for both Host and Extension , i can access this path from my extension.

```
 NSURL *storeURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"com.application"];
```

It only have a /Library path when i get directory and files.

```
NSArray * files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:url error:nil];
[files enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"fileName : %@",(NSString *)obj);
}];
```

My host app's sqlite file is under Documents directory. How can i make this sqlite file available under Shared Container ? Do i need to move whole database ? Any other solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access the data directly from the db file, you will have to place it into the shared container. I don't think there is another option, you can't create slink or anything to the host app.

I was solving similar problem and I decided to use group NSUserDefaults to share the contents that I needed in the Shared extension – because it was just couple variables. That might be a simple one solution

Comment: Thanks for reply. NSUserDefaults is not enough for me and don't want to duplicate data because it can change overtime. I have a sqlite created by xcdatamodel , and i think i have to move this file to shared container ? right ?